# Array object copy updates when object is updated

Tags: powershell

I have this bit of code

```
$subnet = @{
    name = 'subnet-1'
    properties = @{
        addressPrefix = '10.0.0.0/24'
    }
}

$array = @() 

$array += $subnet 

$subnet.properties.addressPrefix = '10.1.0.0/24' 

$array += $subnet 

$array  | ConvertTo-Json
```

Which gives the following output

```
[
    {
        "properties":  {
                           "addressPrefix":  "10.1.0.0/24"
                       },
        "name":  "subnet-1"
    },
    {
        "properties":  {
                           "addressPrefix":  "10.1.0.0/24"
                       },
        "name":  "subnet-1"
    }
]
```

Why does the hashtable value update in the array after it has been added? I thought that `+=` created a copy of the array.

What is the best way to prevent this? (i.e. get the result I'm looking for!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When copying Hash tables, PowerShell uses references, so you need to `Clone` them to force it to make copies:

```
$array += $subnet

$subnet2 = $subnet.Clone()
$subnet2.properties = $subnet.properties.Clone()
$subnet2.properties.addressPrefix = '10.1.0.0/24' 

$array += $subnet2
```

Then the result is:

```
[
    {
        "properties":  {
                           "addressPrefix":  "10.0.0.0/24"
                       },
        "name":  "subnet-1"
    },
    {
        "properties":  {
                           "addressPrefix":  "10.1.0.0/24"
                       },
        "name":  "subnet-1"
    }
]
```